# Is there any age restriction to the use of 'little sister'?

Tags: phrase-usage

I know that 'little sister' means 'younger sister', but the 'little' here gives me the feeling that a 'little sister' refers to a  very young person and that the phrase may primarily be used by parents talking to their children.

If the younger sister is an adult, maybe at her 40s, is it ok to refer to her as 'little sister'? Will that sound weird? Does the same apply to 'little brother'?

Comment: I'm an only child, but I don't think an adult would refer to a younger sibling as 'little' except in an affectionate, semi-humorous way.

Comment: Why vote down the question? As a native speaker, you may think of it as a silly question, but a foreigner is likely to find it confusing. None of the mainstream dictionaries ( for example, thefreedictionary) says anything about this restriction on age, and there is no similar discussion on the first few pages on google. I thought this website was for English learners.

Comment: My partner's little sister is 55.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter! _Little sister_, _baby brother_ and the like normally refer to small children, so you would only introduce an adult as 'my little sister' in very informal circumstances.

Comment: Mine is 71 and still going strong. I guess I'm giving a few things away.

Comment: Yes, there is a very old man up in the sky who hits people with a rod if you get this wrong. Seriously, a person might say little sister even in their later years. However, that is colloquial. Formally, it's younger.

Comment: I refer to my 52-year old brother as my "baby brother" sometimes. But only in a semi-humorous way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly fine to use it even at older ages, but probably not as much. In formal events with friends of others, usually you don't say that. If it is just the two of you, then it is fine whatever you call each other!

In the later years, "younger sister" is more common, and not belittling at all! - @gotube

Comment: +1 and to add in the later years, "younger sister" is more common, and not belittling at all

Comment: Being called "young" is a compliment if you're adult or old (maybe not so much if you're a child), which is another reason to prefer "younger sister".

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are from one of the many languages that has different words for "older sibling" and "younger sibling".

Don't worry. English doesn't have these words.  The usual and correct way to speak of a sister who is younger than you is "sister".  This is true whether your sister is 5 or 50.

If there is some reason that you need the person that you are speaking to know that you are speaking about a sister who is younger than you, then "younger sister" is correct, and "little sister" is an acceptable colloquial or affectionate alternative.

However, it is rare that the relative age actually matters if you are both adults, and so you should not use "younger sister", instead just say "sister".

Answer (score 2):

In Scotland, a common synonym for "little" is "wee" and it is very common to use it to refer to a younger sibling, especially affectionately, regardless of the age of the people concerned. My mum regularly referred to my aunt as her wee sister, even when my mum was in her early 70s and my aunt in her late 60s.

Comment: I remember my Grandpa's older sister, who used to call him 'bebè' (Italian word for `baby`) despite being in her 90s :)